# how to remove space in id attribute runtime angularjs or html?

Tags: html, angularjs

here label contain `id` attribute which get id text from some property file

```
<label id="{{Header.text}}"> </label>
```

but runtime `id` is replaced with text which is having text `"my header"` from property file

```
<label id="my Header">Hello World!</label>
```

i have tried `<label id="{{(Header.text).trim()}}"> </label>`  but its not working, 
problem is `id` contains space between word, i want to remove spaces at runtime when header is renders on web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to create a custom filter and use regular expression to replace the empty space.

```
app.filter('camelize',function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input) {
            return input.replace(/\s+/g, '');    
        }
    }
});
```

Then do ...

```
<h1 id="{{Header.text | camelize}}"> </h1>
```

Comment: can't i do only in `<h1>`  tag ?

Comment: it's an id, why would you want it in the `h1` tag?

Comment: consider it is a label, then how could we do?

Comment: Then just do `<label>{{Header.text | camelize}}</label>`